# Залить прямоугольник цветом, либо как то выделить Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У нас есть лист прямоугольников, случайно разбросанных по всем экрану

```
 private List<Rect> testrect;
```

Не всегда  понятно, где они реально находятся, поэтому хотелось бы как то их выделить - залить цветом, добавить видимые границы или что нибудь в этом роде. Как это сделать? В стандартном C# есть такое решение

```
SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(solidBrush, 0, 0, 100, 60);
```

Но оно, вроде бы, для Windows Forms. 
Пойдет ли такое в Unity? Или есть способ лучше?

Comment: Например в OnGUI отрисовать

Comment: @pavel
Спасибо! А как? Там еще вроде бы координаты в OnGUI идут не так как обычно, y на нуле сверху, на максимуме снизу. 

Т.е. Делаем void OnGUI и там new Rect который совпадает с нашим? Можете в ответе расписать?

Comment: Буду с компа распишу.

Comment: лёгкий оффтоп: исправьте "массив" на "список" - это очень разные вещи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отрисовки на сцене можно в обычном методе `OnGUI` рисовать при помощи [EditorGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.html) и его методов, к примеру [DrawRect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.DrawRect.html).
Он выглядит так:

```
public static void DrawRect(Rect rect, Color color);
```

то есть на вход принимает объект типа `Rect` и красит в цвет `Color`. Простейший вид будет такой:

```
void OnGUI() {         
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    Color color = Color.blue;
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(rect, color);
}
```

Соответственно для всех прямоугольников в списке достаточно по нему пробегаться и отрисовывать, типа такого

```
Color color = Color.blue;

foreach (var rect in list) {
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(rect, color);
}
```

---

Во вкладке `Scene` можно пользоваться методом [OnDrawGizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) и рисовать прямоугольники за счет [Gizmos.DrawGUITexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawGUITexture.html). Соответственно придется текстурку задать прямоугольнику.

```
public Texture2D texture2D; // Тут будет текстура, хотя бы просто материал красный

void OnDrawGizmos() {        
    foreach (var rect in list) {
        Gizmos.DrawGUITexture(rect, texture2D);
    }
}
```

Либо там же рисовать за счет [Gizmos.DrawCube](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawCube.html), просто беря координаты из `rect`

```
void OnDrawGizmos() {       
    // Задаем цвет рисуемого предмета !!!
    Color color = Color.red;

    foreach (var rect in list) {            
        Gizmos.DrawCube(rect.position, rect.size);
    }
}
```